# Display menu in omnetpp

Tags: ubuntu, omnet++, ubuntu-13.04

I'm using omnetpp-4.3.1 and ubuntu 13.4, my problem is I can't display the menu in my omnetpp, so there is anyway to make my menu visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0

in your shell. This is an eclipse issue with ubuntu's global menu system that was fixed in later Eclipse versions. OMNeT++ 4.4 and later already contains this workaround in its launcher script.